# remove elements added with prependTo

Tags: jquery

I use "**prependTo**" **JQuery** method to duplicate form elements but can't **remove** the new element and can't select that !!

Comment: If you want to remove the new element, why prepend it in the first place? Could you please be clear on what you want to achieve??

Comment: Please post some code or jsFiddle that will really help.. my best guess currently that you are having trouble with triggering events on element that are injected to the DOM dynamically but without seeing the code and what you are trying to achieve i can't help..

Comment: Such this code

http://jsfiddle.net/WTHYj/1/

Answer (score 1):

So, not really knowing what you mean i can help a little bit..

you can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3Jymb/1/

**HTML:**
    Add Element
    Remove Element

```
<div id="container">
<div>
    <b>I'm an element</b>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#addElement").click(function(){
    $("#container").prepend("<div class='prepended'><b>I'm a prepended element</b></div>")
});

$("#removeElement").click(function(){
     $(".prepended").eq(1).remove()
});
```

here each pretended element has a special class that tags him as prepended... that way you can remove it ..

If each new prepended element contains a button that suppose to remove it particularly then you will have to use the "On" API that will help you with attaching events to dynamically added DOM elements.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xG69Z/3/

**HTML:**

```
<button id="addElement">Add Element</button>
<button id="removeElement">Remove Element</button>

<div id="container">
<div>
    <b>I'm an element</b>
    <button class="removeMe"> Remove Me</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var i=1;

$("#addElement").click(function(){
    $("#container").prepend("<div class='prepended'><b>I'm a prepended element #"+i+"</b> <button class='removeMe'> Remove Me</button></div>");
    i++;
});

$("#removeElement").click(function(){
     $(".prepended").eq(1).remove()
});

$(document).on("click", ".removeMe", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: If it helps please mark it so using the green "V" so that others may know.